# Adding callback function for wp_ajax_ has no effect

Tags: plugin-development, customization, ajax, plugins, debug

I was trying to add one more callback function to the WordPress AJAX action `woocommerce_apply_coupon`.

This action is defined in the WooCommerce plugin, I want to add my own callback function to this action from my plugin file.

What I have tried:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_apply_coupon','darn',999);
add_action( 'wp_ajax_woocommerce_apply_coupon', 'darn',999);

function darn(){
         print_r($_REQUEST);
         exit;
    }
```

Doing this in my `functions.php` is not even showing any error, like I can't see any effect of this code.

I want to know if this is even possible to achieve . Thank you.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question, but an ajax call is made from a JS script, so I suppose to interact with `woocommerce_ajax_apply_coupon` you should make the call from a JS script

Comment: yes you misunderstood completely

Comment: Have you read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) and/or [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)?

Comment: yap none of them have mentioned anything related to multiple callbacks for a single action

Comment: its okey if this title actually will help others looking for something similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is possible and you're on the right track! :)

**AJAX calls happen "behind the scenes"** and no screen output is generated during the process no matter what you `echo` or `print_r` - that's why you don't see anything returned to you - instead that server response is captured by javascript and acted upon there.

That gives you two basic options for debugging your AJAX actions:

**1) You can use `error_log()` in your AJAX actions to write the output to `WP_DEBUG_LOG` file and check the results there:**

```
function darn(){
     error_log( print_r($_POST, 1) );
     exit;
}
```

For more details see [Codex: Debugging_in_WordPress - WP_DEBUG_LOG](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG)

*Pro-tip #1: Fire up a terminal console and use* `tail -f debug.log` *for a live stream of debugging awesomness ;)*

*Pro-tip #2: Use* `tail -f debug.log | grep -v 'bad-plugin'` *to filter out too much debugging awesomness from plugin authors who don't use* `WP_DEBUG_LOG` *;P*

**2) Use javascript's own `console.log()` to check the response right in your browser:**

Send a response from the AJAX action...

```
function darn(){
    echo 'darn!'
    exit;
}
```

... and receive it with JS:

```
$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    // Response will be 'darn!'
    if( typeof(console) == 'object' ) console.log( response );
});
```

*Pro-tip #3: Instead of simply echoing the response like we did above you can use* [wp_send_json()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json) *for generating a JSON formatted response or* [WP_Ajax_Response](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Ajax_Response) *class for a XML. Handy for more complex responses and/or error handling!*

*Pro-tip #4: Let me know in comments if anything remains unclear :D*

Welcome and have a great time on WPSE!

Comment: thankyou this was very informative ! time to try it out :D

Comment: +1 for `wp_send_json()` I didn't know it and still output json using php `header`. However advantage of _old_ method is possibility to add cache-related headers.

Answer (score 1):

If some other handler code is hooked first and it calls `exit()` too, then the script ends, so your code never runs.

Check the other handler.